# symfony's form_errors displays list item instead of just text

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

[ Symfony 4 ]

I've this template code in Symfony:

```
{{ form_widget(registrationForm.username, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
{{ form_errors(registrationForm.username) }}
```

Instead of just displaying error text, it's generating a list item like this:

```
<ul><li> Username already exists </li></ul>
```

How to not have it generate this list item and just get the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it is correct behavior, cause you can have multiple errors for one field for example "Username is too short" and "Field Username contains inappropriate characters", but to get only first error you can use:

```
{{ form_errors(registrationForm.username|first) }}
```

Or you can customize your form_errors rendering, first create file for form_errors, for example your_form/custom_form_errors.html.twig :

```
{% block form_errors %}
    {% spaceless %}
          <div class="error">{{ errors|first }}</div>
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```

And after that include it to your view file:

```
{% form_theme form 'your_form/custom_form_errors.html.twig' %}

...

{{ form_errors(registrationForm.username) }}
```

Comment: doing what you gave threw a really fat error: `Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\Form\FormRenderer::searchAndRenderBlock() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\Form\FormView`

Comment: how do I give this ul a class, passing `attr` don't work

Answer (score 0):

just to extend @Andrii Filenko 's answer. You can modify the output the `form_errors` or any other form twig function pretty easily. it's called custom theming in Symfony.

Consider this:

```
// templates/register.html.twig

{% extends "base.html.twig" %}

{% form_theme registrationForm _self %}

{% block form_errors %}
  {% spaceless %}
    {% if errors|length > 0 %}
    <ul class="changed list">
        {% for error in errors %}
            <li>{{ error.message }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% endif %}
   {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_errors %}

{% block body %}{% endblock %}
```

Output:

```
<ul class="changed list"><li> Username already exists </li></ul>
```